# VBA Copy visible from table to another table

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, listobject

I have a working code that matches and copies all column data through the headers between 2 tables.

2 functions I need help with :

1. I have a main table "Oculus Trans" from another sheet with 17 columns and I need to filter with which trailers are arriving today and have only those visible rows copied to the reporting table "Table9". I have tried SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
2. On a separate button, I want to select and highlight multiple rows from the main table "Oculus Trans" to be copied on another reporting table "tblSOSTrailersToBeReceived". I have tried ActiveCell.Row

```
Sub TransArrivals()

    Dim lc As Long, mc As Variant, X As Variant
    Dim raw_data As Worksheet, processed_data As Worksheet
    Dim raw_tbl As ListObject, processed_tbl As ListObject

    Set raw_data = Worksheets("Oculus Trans")
    Set processed_data = Worksheets("SOS_Report")
    Set raw_tbl = raw_data.ListObjects("Table9")
    Set processed_tbl = processed_data.ListObjects("tblTransArrival")
    
    With processed_tbl
        'clear target table
        On Error Resume Next
        .DataBodyRange.Clear
        .Resize .Range.Resize(raw_tbl.ListRows.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
On Error Resume Next
        'loop through target header and collect columns from raw_tbl
        For lc = 1 To .ListColumns.Count
            Debug.Print .HeaderRowRange(lc)
            mc = Application.Match(.HeaderRowRange(lc), raw_tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)
            If Not IsError(mc) Then
                X = raw_tbl.ListColumns(mc).DataBodyRange.Value
                .ListColumns(lc).DataBodyRange = X
            End If
        Next lc

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code in the workbook with the tables? Could you share the lines of code that filter `tblTransArrival`?

Comment: `Const DST_DATE_TITLE As String = "ETA"`

Comment: `Sub Shift_Arrival()

Dim in_time As Double, out_time As Double

in_time = Date + TimeValue("00:00")
out_time = Date + TimeValue("23:59")

transoculus.ListObjects("Table9").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:=">=" & in_time, Criteria2:="<=" & out_time

End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

### Return Filtered Values in Another Excel Table (ListObject)

- This will copy the whole data and then remove the undesired rows (in the destination). Otherwise, it would become very complicated.

```vb
Sub PopulateTransArrivalsToday()
 
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Oculus Trans"
    Const SRC_TABLE As String = "Table9"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "SOS_Report"
    Const DST_TABLE As String = "tblTransArrival"
    Const DST_DATE_TITLE As String = "Date"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(SRC_SHEET)
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects(SRC_TABLE)
    
    With slo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects(DST_TABLE)
    Dim dCol As Long: dCol = dlo.ListColumns(DST_DATE_TITLE).Index
    
    With dlo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        If .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .ListRows.Add
        Else
            .DataBodyRange.Clear
        End If
        .Resize .Range.Resize(slo.Range.Rows.Count)
    End With
    
    Dim scIndexes:
    scIndexes = Application.Match(dlo.HeaderRowRange, slo.HeaderRowRange, 0)
      
    Dim sc As Long
      
    For sc = 1 To UBound(scIndexes)
        dlo.ListColumns(sc).DataBodyRange.Value _
            = slo.ListColumns(scIndexes(sc)).DataBodyRange.Value
    Next sc
    
    dlo.Range.AutoFilter dCol, "<>" & CDbl(Date)
    
    Dim frg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set frg = dlo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    dlo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    If Not frg Is Nothing Then frg.Delete xlShiftUp
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Subscript out of range from this line. Thank you and Sorry since im still new to this.
`dlo.ListColumns(sc).DataBodyRange.Value = slo.ListColumns(scIndexes(sc)).DataBodyRange.Value`

Comment: That would mean that there is at least one destination column title that can't be found in source. You could check if that's true or wrap it between the following two lines: `If IsNumeric(scIndexes(c)) Then` ... `End If`. When the error occurs, in the code hover over the `sc` variable which represents the current destination column, and try to find its title in source. Also, don't forget to adjust the title of the date column (`DST_DATE_TITLE`).